# Why most apps try to use OSS if /dev/dsp is present?

Tags: linux, audio, oss

So why most applications apparently try to use OSS if `/dev/dsp` is present on a system where more advanced audio servers (ALSA or PulseAudio) are also available?

I experience this after installing `oss-compat` on Debian Wheezy. Apparently for example the following apps seem to start using OSS no matter what else is available:

- MPlayer
- SDL (anything using the SDL library, such as Battle for Wesnoth)
- mpg321
- ogg123
- (third party) Firefox's (third party) Flash plugin

The reason for trying this is not quite relevant for the question, however check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171207/how-to-make-pulseaudio-and-oss-only-applications-coexist-on-debian-wheezy) if interested.

For me it would seem the more logical if applications (which are capable to use those) probed for the more advanced audio solutions first, and only tried to access OSS (`/dev/dsp`) when none is found.

Comment: If the problem is just pulseaudio compatibility, have a look at, e.g., `mpg123 --list-modules`, and the `-o` switch in `man mpg123`.  I think some of this is poor incorporation of pulseaudio by debian, but that is just a hunch.

Comment: @goldilocks Yep, I already patched this around since long with startup scipts to force stuff explicitly to use ALSA for which it was appropriate, memorizing commands where necessary, or for others, to use `aoss` etc., so things work fine as now, it seems, my current take is still the most pleasant solution considering my need for some OSS only apps which even break with PulseAudio's `padsp` (I don't have PulseAudio installed in this setup).

Comment: Keep in mind if you *don't* have pulse, you can't multiplex sound, so if something tries to make a noise while something else is using sound, it will be disappointed.  ALSA and OSS are only one thing at a time.

Comment: @goldilocks There is no true OSS, just `oss-compat`. Truly I shouldn't even need that, as `aoss` is supposed to work without it, but I can't figure out to save my soul, how. ALSA can multiplex, OSS stuff, as long as started through `aoss` will also happily cooperate (I am listening music even right now, and sure at least one Flash advert is here somewhere :) ).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this is what's up: http://olicomber.co.uk/blog/b/Multiplexing_ALSA_input_streams_with_DMIX/ Anyway, you have a good question in here somewhere, lol -- probably plural.  You have to go at this in terms of the individual applications.

Comment: @goldilocks I put a little insert in the last sentence of my question. Hope it comes through more clearly that way (maybe this whole conversation could have been avoided with that). Thanks for the link, thankfully my system was not **that** cruel (ALSA apps mostly cooperating fine out-of-the-box)! But hope I will find the cure for my `aoss` problem in there, gaining some better insight!

Answer (score 2):

> it would seem the more logical if applications probed for the more advanced audio solutions first

I would guess there's actually a big advantage to this, having done a little with the ALSA API.  [Here's where you start](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html), in order to just play a prepped PCM stream.

Now I'll cite wikipedia on [the OSS API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System#API):

> The API is designed to use the traditional Unix framework of open(),
>   read(), write(), and ioctl(), via special devices. For instance, the
>   default device for sound input and output is /dev/dsp. Examples using
>   the shell:
>
> ```
>    cat /dev/urandom > /dev/dsp # plays white noise through the speaker
>    cat /dev/dsp > a.a # reads data from the microphone and copies it to file a.a
> ```

Which one do you want to start with -- the more advanced and complicated one, or the simple and foolproof one?  I imagine it depends what you want to do, but presuming most applications just want to stream some pcm out, writing to `/dev/dsp` should be fine.

[I'm also presuming plain PCM *can* be fed directly to `/dev/dsp` (if not then what?), but I can't test it because smarty-pants that I am, all my machines here have custom kernels with no OSS support!  I might just change my tune on that in the future.]

Comment: I can understand this standpoint for an OSS only application: the author gone down the easiest path. What I don't understand are those for example I mentioned: they are all capable to use at least ALSA (and typically more), yet they still fall in for a `/dev/dsp` as soon as they see one (which becomes annoying fast when actually having ALSA, but needing `oss-compat` for a few OSS only things).

Comment: Okay, but: Note what I said about how my systems *don't* have OSS support.  That means for greatest portability you would need to provide both OSS-only and non-OSS ALSA.  I.e., you need to implement both.  Then if what you need to do can be done with OSS, it probably has marginally lower overhead, so you might as well start with that.  Why use a more complex tool when a simpler one will suffice if available?

Comment: Uh. I was asking this from an user's viewpoint, who wishes to use applications which already do support both OSS and ALSA, not from a developer's viewpoint, who is just about to decide which path he should take first. That is, that why (most?) applications which already support both (or even more) will still use OSS if they happen to find a `/dev/dsp` (I don't know, maybe this is even rather specific to Debian, that they compile / set up things this way for the distro).

Comment: If the developer wants to give the user a choice, s/he's free to do that.  However, nobody writes software such that *every* decision point is user configurable.  In this case it's hard to see why this would matter to the user -- if the app is supposed to play sound and it does, and on a variety of systems, most people could care less what mechanism was used.  BTW, you haven't actually said *how* you've made this observation.  If you don't have any counter examples (exceptions which use ALSA and not `/dev/dsp`), I would be dubious of the methodology.

Comment: I installed `oss-compat` on my ALSA based system to get an OSS app working, and suddenly a hell of complaints for `/dev/dsp` being busy... (usually Firefox reserving it for itself for some stupid Flash ad, then I can't start a music player, or test an SDL app I am developing - these all use ALSA when no `/dev/dsp` is present, and work happily, simultaneously). So far I didn't find any counter-examples on my system, so seems systematic. I don't understand why. Is there a standard on this then, or what?

Comment: Yeah, I just had a look at your other question.  If you are using pulse, you don't want things using OSS.  Or ALSA, if I recall (pulse is something else I prefer to disable).  You should check into the individual apps and see if they do allow you to specify this (as with mpg123).

Comment: In the "stable" patchwork solution, I have no PulseAudio. I only installed it recently (along with removing the patchwork) for testing out the `padsp` solution properly, but after some experimenting I reverted to my nice patchy mess which at least works :)